# Flex and embedded XML

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm using Parsley IoC in my current Flex project. So I'd like to embed the container configuration XML onto the result SWF.

How could I load embedded XML file into action script XML object?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use XML?  If you configure Parsely via AS or MXML it will be compiled in and will be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

My XML file has  declaration in it so I needed the octet solution from http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Embedding_assets_with_application_octet_stream-8046.html instead of Antti's answer's link.